# Python/X11: find out if user switches virtual desktops

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, x11

I'm looking for a way to determine if the user switches virtual desktops under X11.

I'm using Python with X11 libraries and PyGTK. I found some working examples in C, but I lack the expertise to translate them into Python, and I read the source code of several X11 pager applications (fbpanel, pypanel), but I can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

Do I have to register for a signal? Using X11 or GTK?
Do I have to busy-wait?

I'm completely new to both X11 and GTK, so any hints/help would be greatly appreciated.

Greets,
Philip

PS: My current efforts can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/neap/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a GTK based solution:

```
screen = gtk.gdk.screen_get_default()
root = screen.get_root_window()
root.set_events(gtk.gdk.SUBSTRUCTURE_MASK)
root.add_filter(event_filter)

def event_filter(event, user_data):
        # process event
        return gtk.gdk.FILTER_CONTINUE
```

Apparently, the SUBSTRUCTURE_MASK contains events which are typically associated with workspace switches. Nevertheless, this solution feels a bit awkward. Any ideas?

Greets,
Philip

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at [libwnck](http://library.gnome.org/devel/libwnck/stable/), or possibly its Python bindings.

Comment: I have already looked into libwnck (which is exceptionally neat), but I don't want to add another dependency to the program when I can as well solve it using X11/GTK.

Answer (score 0):

Typically a desktop change is announced to clients by a property change on the root window,
so listen for PROPERTY_CHANGE_MASK instead of SUBSTRUCTURE_MASK;
that will give you a lot less noise.

As for *which* property changes, I suspect that differs among
different windowmanagers/desktops/whatever;  I'm running ubuntu/unity and
when I do "xprop -root" before and after a desktop switch, and diff the results,
I find that the property that changed is _NET_DESKTOP_VIEWPORT.

The primary noise I get in addition is that the root window's
_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW property changes each time the active window changes.

Answer (score 0):

One more refinement: instead of `GDK_SUBSTRUCTURE_MASK`, as [Don Hatch says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22421858/673852), use `GDK_PROPERTY_CHANGE_MASK`. Moreover, the exact property that you're interested in is `_NET_CURRENT_DESKTOP`. It's a 32-bit property, whose value is a 0-based desktop number.

Here's the complete compilable and runnable example that catches the moment of desktop switch and reports the number of current desktop after that. The example is in C since I'm not fluent in Python, I hope you can translate.

```c
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <gdk/gdkx.h>

GdkFilterReturn propertyChangeFilter(GdkXEvent* xevent, GdkEvent*e, gpointer data)
{
    const XPropertyEvent*const propEvt=(const XPropertyEvent*)xevent;

    if(propEvt->type!=PropertyNotify)
        return GDK_FILTER_CONTINUE;
    if(propEvt->state!=PropertyNewValue)
        return GDK_FILTER_CONTINUE;
    const Atom NET_CURRENT_DESKTOP=(Atom)data;
    if(propEvt->atom!=NET_CURRENT_DESKTOP)
        return GDK_FILTER_CONTINUE;

    fprintf(stderr, "Desktop change detected\n");
    Atom actualType;
    int actualFormat;
    unsigned long nitems, remainingBytes;
    unsigned char* prop;
    if(XGetWindowProperty(propEvt->display, propEvt->window, propEvt->atom,
                          0, 1, False, AnyPropertyType,
                          &actualType, &actualFormat, &nitems, &remainingBytes,
                          &prop) != Success)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to get current desktop number\n");
        return GDK_FILTER_CONTINUE;
    }
    if(nitems!=1 || remainingBytes!=0 || actualFormat!=32)
    {
        XFree(prop);
        fprintf(stderr, "Unexpected number of items (%lu) or remaining bytes (%lu)"
                        " or format (%d)\n", nitems, remainingBytes, actualFormat);
        return GDK_FILTER_CONTINUE;
    }
    guint32 value;
    memcpy(&value, prop, sizeof value);
    XFree(prop);
    fprintf(stderr, "Current desktop: %u\n", value);

    return GDK_FILTER_CONTINUE;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    gtk_init(&argc,&argv);

    GdkDisplay*const gdkDisplay=gdk_display_get_default();
    Display*const display=gdk_x11_display_get_xdisplay(gdkDisplay);
    const Atom atom=XInternAtom(display, "_NET_CURRENT_DESKTOP", True);
    GdkWindow*const root=gdk_get_default_root_window();
    gdk_window_set_events(root, GDK_PROPERTY_CHANGE_MASK);
    gdk_window_add_filter(root, propertyChangeFilter, (gpointer)atom);

    gtk_main();
}
```